# Is there a way to display Task LastModifiedBy in a custom object list view?

Tags: custom-object, formula, list-view

I have a need to display the date and time of the last logged call on a given account in a list view. It can't be done directly as far as I know, so my thinking was to create a field on the custom object that uses a formula to pull LastModifiedBy (as I understand it, this also carries the timestamp info?)? I've exhausted my limited knowledge at this point...

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a trigger around the tasks object.

- Create a lookup field to User in your custom object
- Create a trigger on the task object. The trigger logic should check if the task is associated to a record from your custom object, and in case fetch the user and populate your lookup field. Bare in mind that Task has a polymorphic relationship, meaning that your trigger will have to [deal with that](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_polymorph_keys.htm).

I hope it helps,
L